# Error on Opening "Manage Data Modelling" in Excel 2019

Tags: excel, data-modeling, add-in

([ErrorScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji5xZ.png)

(one of the data analysis add-ins can't be enabled. an error occurred and this add-in is no longer functioning properly. Try reinstalling excel.)

This Error comes while clicking on "Manage Data Modelling" in excel-2019 and did not open Data Modelling Window. Screenshot attached.

Comment: So did you reinstall excel?

Comment: Yes I did, but same error after reinstalled.